# IntelliJ Show Diff Includes Unversioned Files

Tags: intellij-idea

After upgrading to IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2 Ultimate Edition, I've noticed now that when I go to the Commit pane and select Show Diff on a file in the Default Changelist, that it includes the Unversioned Files in the set of files for the diff comparison.

That is, say I only change one line of code in `pom.xml` but I also have some un-versioned file, let's say called `temp.sql`. If I open the Show Diff tool by select Show Diff from `pom.xml` in the Default Changelist, then the Compare to Next File button is still enabled. Clicking it takes me to `temp.sql`, though I have no desire to look at it since I don't even have it in source control.

For example, here I have a Default Changelist with a change to one file in source control, `pom.xml`. And I have an un-versioned file called `temp.sql`.
[image: commit pane]

When I select Show Diff on a file in the Default Changlist, it should, in my opinion, and in my previous version of IntelliJ, only show you...the Default Changelist, which is `pom.xml`. Instead it is giving me `pom.xml` and `temp.sql`.
[image: diff window]

Is this a new feature? It seems like a bug to me. I can't seem to find any documentation for it. I can't find any way to turn it off.

I see there is a "Show unversioned files" check box in the Version Control > Commit section of Preferences, but clicking it doesn't seem to change anything.
[image: version control commit preferences]

Comment: How do the files look in project view? Are they excluded, or located in the excluded folder? Or they are just added to .gitignore?

Comment: they're not versioned files. just local files.

Comment: How are they marked in IntelliJ IDEA? Try to make them excluded in file's (folder's) context menu in the Project view.

Comment: It seems that you have faced known issue, please feel free to vote:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-237528

Comment: @RuslanKuleshov, ok. Yeah I guess that I didn't find IDEA-237528 because it didn't mention anything about the Unversioned File list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If I choose Show Diff on the Default Changelist object, rather than on a file in the Default Changelist, that it restricts navigation to the files in the change list as I want. It's only if I select Show Diff from a file in the Default Changelist that includes all files in all change lists, including un-versioned files.
2. [Ruslan Kuleshov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12360005/ruslan-kuleshov) made a comment that this seems like a known issue, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-237528.

> **New commit tool: don't jump to other changelist's changes**

> I always review all changes on the current changelist before commit. I focus the diff preview and use F7 to jump through all changes on all files. Previously, when I reached the last file F7 stopped jumping to other files. But after enabling the new tool, when I press F7 on the last changed file on the current changelist, it jumps to the first change on the next changelist. That's a problem since I can begin reviewing changes which are not intended for commiting right now, loosing time, confusing me and even risking to mix files from different changesets.

I had failed to find that issue on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com because I hadn't yet tried having files in source control with changes in a non-default change list. I was only searching YouTrack for the fact that Show Diff now includes un-versioned files.

So, it seems that if you choose Show Diff from a file in a change list, then the diff comparison tool will now include *all files* in the set of files, regardless which change list they are in and regardless whether they are in source control yet.

I think that this is a bug and have voted for the issue. I encourage others to do so as well.